# Word for both dimensions and weight

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a word for both dimensions (length, width, height) and weight?

Comment: I think measurements covers it, I soon realised that after posting

Comment: sure let's wrap this sucker up then.

Comment: In popular parlance, ***mass*** is often used in respect of the *size* of something. Plus obviously there's *weight = mass [under the influence of gravity]*.

Comment: I have never seen or heard "mass" used to mean the "size" of something.  But that's just me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is maybe "measurements".

If you're trying to find wording for a web site or computer interface, you should really tell us that (people love those sort of questions) and please give the full total example, really with an image